# Cytoscape.js cy.style(): replace selector instead of adding

Tags: cytoscape.js

I wrote a simple edge editing function, as I'm unable to install the extension. Here's what I do on every control nodes movement:

```
  this.cy.style().selector(`[id = '${id}']`).style({
     'control-point-distances': bendDistances.join(' '),
     'control-point-weights': bendWeights.join(' ')
  }).update()
```

`id` is the id of active edge. I was expecting this code to replace matching `'control-point-distances'` and `'control-point-weights'` every time I call it, if selector is the same. However it isn't the case. I get this in my serialized style:

```
{"selector":"[id = \"6\"]","style":{"control-point-distances":"107px -50px","control-point-weights":"-0.082 0.8"}},
{"selector":"[id = \"6\"]","style":{"control-point-distances":"107px 53px","control-point-weights":"-0.082 0.499"}},
{"selector":"[id = \"6\"]", ...
```

How can I replace the same selectors on core? Or how can I check their existance and remove them first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update a cytoscape.js style currently.

There are 2 ways in my mind. The best is to use a function style

```
    .selector('edge')
      .style({
        'background-color': function( ele ){ return ele.data('bg') }
```

Here you should check the id of the edge and do things accordingly. Check "function format" https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/format

The second way is to reset the style always.

```
cy.style()
  .clear() // start a fresh stylesheet without even the default stylesheet

  // define all basic styles for node
  .selector('node')
    .style('background-color', 'magenta')

  // define all basic styles for edge
  .selector('edge')
      .style({
      'width': 3,
      'line-color': 'yellow'
    })

  // ...

  .update() // indicate the end of your new stylesheet so that it can be updated on elements
;
```

Check https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.style

Comment: The first solution is not serializable, as far as I understand?

Comment: what do you mean by "serializable"? I know that Functional styles cannot be exported as JSON strings with methods such as `var styleJson = cy.style().json();
var serializedJson = JSON.stringify( styleJson );` You would see `fn` for functional styles

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly cy.style().json(). So I'll have to go with something like second approach. Thank you

Comment: I think you can also store functions as JSON by generating functions from plain strings. But you should do some extra work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function